# I can't get console.log to output anything

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have no knowledge whatsoever in console logging but I watched someone do something similar and I kind of added my own part to it. But I can't seem to get it to output anything. Could someone explain why this is? I've looked at some of the other similar answers on this site but I don't think any of them help my case.

```
const ipKey = "apiKey";
const vpnKey = "apiKey";
const ip = "ip_address";


const getVPN = async (ip) => {
    let vpn_url = `https://vpnapi.io/api/${ip}?key=${vpnKey}`;

    await fetch(vpn_url).then((response) =>
        response.json().then((json) => {
            const output= `
                -----------------
                VPN: ${response['security']}
                -----------------`;
            console.log(output);
        })
    );
};

const getLocation = async (ip) => {
    let ip_url = `https://ipgeolocation.abstractapi.com/v1/?api_key=${ipKey}&ip_address=${ip}`;

    await fetch(ip_url).then((response) =>
        response.json().then((json) => {
            const output= `
                IP Address: ${response['ip_address']}
                Country: ${response['country']}
                State: ${response['region']}
                City: ${response['city']}
                Zip Code: ${response['postal_code']}
                Lat/Long: ${response['latitude']}, ${response['longitude']}

                -------------------------------
                `;
            console.log(output);
        })
    );
};

getVPN();
getLocation();
```

Okay so it turns out it was something really basic and I did get it to work but then a new problem arised. The code above is updated but now the response from the request always comes back as `ip is undefined`. To my understanding, I added the `ip` variable in the right areas so what could be the issue?

Comment: You're not calling the functions anywhere.

Comment: If nothing is being logged, a reasonable inference would be that the lines calling `console.log()` are never reached.

Answer (score 0):

try to console.log() the functions that contain your existing console.log `console.log(getVPN);` and `console.log(getLocation);` and change your existing console.logs to be `return output;`

So it should look something like this.

```js
const ipKey = "apiKey";
const vpnKey = "apiKey";
const ip = "ip_address";


const getVPN = async (ip) => {
    let vpn_url = `https://vpnapi.io/api/${ip}?key=${vpnKey}`;

    await fetch(vpn_url).then((response) =>
        response.json().then((json) => {
            const output= `
                -------------------------------
                VPN: ${response['security']['vpn']}
                `;
            return output;
        })
    );
};

console.log(getVPN);

const getLocation = async (ip) => {
    let ip_url = `https://ipgeolocation.abstractapi.com/v1/?api_key=${ipKey}&ip_address=${ip}`;

    await fetch(ip_url).then((response) =>
        response.json().then((json) => {
            const output= `
                IP Address: ${response['ip_address']}
                Country: ${response['country']}
                State: ${response['region']}
                City: ${response['city']}
                Zip Code: ${response['postal_code']}
                Lat/Long: ${response['latitude']}, ${response['longitude']}
                
                -------------------------------
                `;
            return output;
        })
    );
};

console.log(getLocation);
```

Comment: When I ran your code, there was an output but it was something along the lines of "async something something". It's working now though! (partially) If you don't mind, could you it another look?

Comment: can you share the full details of the error message?

Comment: ```async (ip) => {
    let vpn_url = `https://vpnapi.io/api/${ip}?key=${vpnKey}`;

    await fetch(vpn_url).then((response) =>
        response.json().then((json) => {
            const output= `
      …``` I don't think it's an error message though

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
const ipKey = "apiKey";
const vpnKey = "apiKey";
const ip = "ip_address";


const getData = async (ip) => {

    let vpn_url = `https://vpnapi.io/api/${ip}?key=${vpnKey}`;

    await fetch(vpn_url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(response => console.log(`
        -------------------------------
        VPN: ${response['security']['vpn']}
        `))
        
    
    let ip_url = `https://ipgeolocation.abstractapi.com/v1/?api_key=${ipKey}&ip_address=${ip}`;

    await fetch(ip_url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(response => console.log(`
        IP Address: ${response['ip_address']}
        Country: ${response['country']}
        State: ${response['region']}
        City: ${response['city']}
        Zip Code: ${response['postal_code']}
        Lat/Long: (${response['latitude']}, ${response['longitude']})

        -------------------------------
        `)
    );
};

getData(ip);
```